# Does have Nuxt 2 not sufficient Typescript support

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs, nuxt.js, ts-jest

I installed  Nuxt 2 with npx create-nuxt-app . Went for the options:Typescript, jest, universal etc... But When you look at the testfiles, they are all spec.js. When changed to spec.ts you are promted to install types/jest (npm i --save-dev @types/jest) and add it to tsconfig types field:"types": [ "jest"]. So far so good. But when running the tests the file imported into such a spec.ts can`t be found. Than I did some research and found a repository:

https://github.com/lakhbawa/nuxtjs-vue-vuetify-vue-test-utils-jest-sample-project

Well this guy is setting up a Next 2 Typescript project with jest, but all the testfile are spec.js. Now I wonder, if Nuxt 2 is lacking complete Typescript support.
P.S: I know Nuxt 2  so old, but I need it for a job.

Comment: The project is 4 years old so quite obsolete. Also, you can run TS on `.js` files, as stated in the [config here](https://github.com/lakhbawa/nuxtjs-vue-vuetify-vue-test-utils-jest-sample-project/blob/master/tsconfig.json#L12). So not a big deal. But yeah, try to move forward towards Nuxt3 since Vue2 is now EOL.